# Passing values from the master page to the content page

Tags: c#, master-pages

Whats the best way to transfer data between the master page and the content page? I am accessing a rather large cache in the master page to display some information but the content page also needs to access the cache. So instead of loading the cache twice i thought it would be better to get the cache from the master page.

I created an interface witch i then use in my master page.

```
IMaster: myClass GetDataCache { get; } 
MasterPage: public partial class main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage, IMaster
```

Then i cast the master page inside my content page and retrieve the cache.

```
IMaster masterPage = (IMaster)Master;
myClass = masterPage.GetDataCache;
```

My question is, is this the best way to handle data between a master page and a content page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) directive inside the ASPX page to get a strongly typed reference to the master page from within your content page (and from the code-behind of your content page).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather leave the master page for the UI only.

The better way would be to have a static singleton class accessible from all content pages for this purpose.

Comment: How would that singleton work. The cache that i am getting is specific for that user.

Comment: You can have that object retrieve the data and store it in session if its user specific. Session is the place to cache user specific data.